# Date Validation in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, date, mongoose

I want the user to input his date of birth. And I would want it be in format YYYY-MM-DD. Node-Validator right now validates all date format, not a particular format. So If I input 12324433 , it is also validated as it thinks its epoch time.

Please help me out as to what should I do? 
This question is specific to validation in Mongoose

Comment: There are a few different projects with similar naming. Which are you using exactly? [`node-validator` on Github](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) ([`validator` on NPM](https://npmjs.org/package/validator))? [`node-validation` on NPM](https://npmjs.org/package/node-validation)? other?

Comment: https://github.com/chriso/node-validator/blob/master/lib/validators.js or as you mentioned node-validator on Github and validator on NPM. I had mentioned it above actually. But that does not matter tell me how can I validate it.

Answer (score 15):

I'm a big fan of [`express-form`](https://github.com/dandean/express-form), def worth a look -- you can also use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/). I've used it myself a for this very reason

from moment.js docs:

```
moment("2011-10-10", "YYYY-MM-DD").isValid(); // true
moment("2011-10-50", "YYYY-MM-DD").isValid(); // false (bad day of month)
```

Cheers, I hope this helps :)

ps - [moment.js github url](https://github.com/timrwood/moment) just in case.

Comment: Like David I have found moment very handy for this task. It really handles these tasks well.

Comment: Note: It is not intended to be used to validate that the input string matches the format string. Because the strictness of format matching can vary depending on the application and business requirements, this sort of validation is not included in Moment.js. This is in the docs itself. Do you still think that I should use their validation method? And Not the regex thing mentioned above?

Comment: I think they just mean to be careful with it and make sure you're sanitizing your timestamp -- I wouldn't require moment only for their validation, I would simply do a RegEx like the only below if it was for this exclusive use case. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry your method is not suitable as before I can call mongoose validate method, mongoose has converted the string to a date object. Even if its a integer, it treats it as epoch time and converts it. Please check for updated question(made an edit to mongoose validation)

Comment: @David I can't do that also in mongoose validation.

Comment: @David this is not working for me : 11-03-197 and 11-32-197 ,  value = moment(date,'DD-MM-YYYY');  moment(value).isValid(); give me like valid , why ?

Comment: I've solved, the right is  moment(value,'DD-MM-GGGG',true).isValid()

Comment: @stackdave your method worked for me. But can you please explain what is meant by 'GGGG'?

Comment: @evilMinion sorry i use date-fns now, not more moment ,it was complicate manage dates and formats

Answer (score 3):

As Node-Validator's documentation points out, *"regex is probably a better choice"*.
I whipped up a regex that looks pretty good, and I believe it'll get the job done, but I advise you to test it thoroughly, if you plan to use it.

```
/\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])/
```

This regex will validate a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD, that you need.
You can see a working code snippet that uses it here:
http://tinker.io/c269b/

Good luck!

**Edit:**
I noticed something that breaks it. This regex validates partial matches, so an input like "1970-01-011" checks out as valid. This happens because I forgot to add the *start* and *end* markers inside the regex. This is how it looks after I fixed it:

```
/^\d\d\d\d-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])$/
```

The example on Tinker is also updated with the fix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How thoroughly does it need to be tested?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just tried out a few different inputs I could think of, and that's it. I know that it deals well with months ranging from 01 - 12 and days ranging from 01 - 31. Try and see if you can come up with something else that might break it.

Comment: Sorry your method is not suitable as before I can call mongoose validate method, mongoose has converted the string to a date object. Even if its a integer, it treats it as epoch time and converts it. Please check for updated question(made an edit to mongoose validation)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. If the value returns as a Date object from mongoose, how could you validate it to find out if the original user input was valid? It sounds like you should be validating user input at an earlier part of the sequence, preferably when the user input was just submitted and your server starts handling it.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was also looking into this and was checking express validator as well, I mocked up a regex as well that might help you out with validating dates.

```
((19|2\d)\d\d)-((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))-((0?[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01]))
```

Here is an image that explains it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
//let pdateFormat = "YYYYMMDDHHmmss";
//let pdateStr = "20210228005959";

let pdateFormat = 'YYYYMMDDHH:mm';
let pdateStr = '2021022823:59';
```

**validateDateFormat (pdateFormat, pdateStr);**

```js
function validateDateFormat(dateFormat, dateStr) {
  if (dateFormat.length != dateStr.length) {
    return false;
  }

  let dateIdentifierArr = {
    year: 'YYYY',
    month: 'MM',
    date: 'DD',
    hour: 'HH',
    minute: 'mm',
    second: 'ss',
  };

  let dateConstructVar = {};
  for (var key in dateIdentifierArr) {
    if (dateFormat.indexOf(dateIdentifierArr[key]) != -1) {
      let index = dateFormat.indexOf(dateIdentifierArr[key]);
      dateConstructVar[key] = dateStr.substring(
        index,
        index + dateIdentifierArr[key].length
      );
    } else {
      dateConstructVar[key] = '00';
    }
  }

  let newDate = new Date(
    +dateConstructVar['year'],
    dateConstructVar['month'] - 1,
    +dateConstructVar['date'],
    dateConstructVar['hour'],
    dateConstructVar['minute'],
    dateConstructVar['second']
  );
  if (
    dateConstructVar['year'] != newDate.getFullYear() ||
    dateConstructVar['month'] != ('0' + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) ||
    dateConstructVar['date'] != ('0' + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2) ||
    dateConstructVar['hour'] != ('0' + newDate.getHours()).slice(-2) ||
    dateConstructVar['minute'] != ('0' + newDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) ||
    dateConstructVar['second'] != ('0' + newDate.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
  ) {
    console.log('Invalid Date');
  }

  console.log(newDate);
}
```